# Inheritence in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I have already created a database using EF Code First. I have implemented a TPH in my model classes. I mean, there is a Person class which is the parent of the Customer class. When I attempted to create the DB at first, only one table named Persons has created that includes a column named Discriminator, just as expected.

Now I am wondering how that column is disappeared!!I've recreated the DB but still no Discriminator filed is there! Does it make any trouble if I make the column directly in the SQL Server? What is the best solution for that?

I really don't know why it disappeared!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

make discriminator a public  property get/set if want to see it on the DB

```
public discriminator {get; set;} // consider virtual if want change tracking proxy
```